# Delphi - Clear Param Data for TADOStoredProc

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

for BDE, we can clear the param data like below.

```
 with tstoredproc do
    begin
    .
    .
      for i := 0 to ParamCount - 1 do Params[i].Clear;
    .
    .

    end
```

how to do the same for ADO Dataset's? I do not want to create params. i am using TADOStoredProc component and it is having all the params. i Just need to clear data and assign new data.

```
with TADoStoredProc do
begin
.
.
 for i := 0 to ParamCount - 1 do Parameters[i].Value := null; -- is this right? or can i use below line of code
 Parameters.Refresh
.
.
end;
```

Comment: @kobik : MySP.Parameters.Clear is deleting all the params. so system is throwing error parameter not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BDE `TParam.Clear` sets `Unassigned` for the data member of the parameter.

> i Just need to clear data and assign new data

Why do you need to clear the data/value in the first place? simply assign the new values.

If you need to explicitly pass `null` to the stored procedure parameter you can use e.g.

```
Parameters[i].Value := Unassigned
```

Comment: there are some scenarios where i need to call the same stored proc again and again by passing different values. so i want to set null values first and then assign values and open the dataset (AdoQuery/ADoStoredProc).

Comment: @DelphiLearner that is redundant, though. You don't need to null a parameter that you are going to assign a non-null value to afterwards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : i am not going to assign all the values. stored proc has 8 params . depending on the condition i am going to assign parameter values. and for each call it changes the parameter values. so before assigning values i want assign them to NULL. if it is not required to assign null in this scenario also, please let me know. i will remove that code.

Comment: @DelphiLearner: again, you DO NOT need to assign null to a parameter that you are going to assign a non-null value to. That is just a waste of time and effort. For each parameter, if you have a new value for it, assign the value, otherwise assign null.  Repeat 8 times. Done.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you very much.